# Python 3.6.2 loop not working like I wanted it too

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently writing a code for my GCSE coursework and I am kind of stuck with my for loop which also contains an if-else statement.
I have done a code similar to this earlier in the program and it works perfectly fine but for some reason this part doesn't and I was wondering if someone could help me.

What I am trying to do is make a quiz type program and the part that I need help with is choosing the subject that the user wants to do.
The user has to type in their preferred subject but if they type the subject in wrong, or type in something invalid, then the program should allow the user to type it in again.
So far, if you type in a subject correctly the first time, the program will proceed to the next stage. 
However, if you type it incorrectly the first time, it will ask the user to try again. But if you type it in correctly the second time, it will again ask the user to try again. Instead of having the program make the user type the subject again, even though it should've been valid the when they typed it in correctly, I want the program to proceed to the next stage.

Available subjects:

```
subjects = []

algebra = ("algebra")
computing = ("computing")

subjects.append(algebra)
subjects.append(computing)
```

Part that I need help with:

```
with open("student_file.csv", "a+") as studentfile:
    studentfileReader = csv.reader(studentfile, delimiter = ',')
    studentfileWriter = csv.writer(studentfile, delimiter = ',')

print("Available subjects:\n-Algebra\n-Computing\n")
ChosenSubject = input("What subject would you like to do? ")
ChosenSubject.lower()

for i in range(2): 
    if ChosenSubject in subjects:
        print("\n")
        break

    else:
        print("\nPlease try again.")
        ChosenSubject == input("What subject would you like to do?")
        ChosenSubject.lower()

if ChosenSubject in subjects:
    print("working")

else:
    print("You keep typing in something incorrect.\nPlease restart the program.")
```

Comment: `ChosenSubject == input("What subject would you like to do?")`

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but style tip: you can populate a list without creating variables for each element and appending them one at a time. You can just do `subjects = ["algebra", "computing"]`

Comment: I suggest that you work on your debugging skills. You can add `print()` statements in your code to see what it is doing or you can learn how to use a debugger such as `pdb` or one in an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop just iterates over a collection of objects. Consider a list `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. On each iteration over `my_list` using `for` loop, it fetches one of the elements in order without repetition. `range(2)` is equivalent to `[0, 1]`.

Try this:

```
print("Available subjects:\n-Algebra\n-Computing\n")


for i in range(2): 
    # `i` is 0 on first iteration and 1 on second. We are not using `i` anywhere since all we want is to loop :) 
    chosen_subject = input("What subject would you like to do? ")

    if chosen_subject.lower() in subjects:
        print("\n")
        break

if chosen_subject.lower() in subjects:
    print("working")

else:
    print("You keep typing in something incorrect.\nPlease restart the program.")
```

Comment: This answer give no insight on why the error happened and took logic from my post. I'm really not looking to get the rep, but only trying to say that at least if you take code from other answers and get accepted, please provide feedback to explain your solution. _try this_  won't  help future users reading that post.

Answer (score 1):

In the else block, perhaps you'd want to replace the '==' with '='.

Also do you want to give the user just two tries or keep asking them until they answer correctly? (The latter is what I inferred from your question, for that I'd recommend using continue)

Comment: These are the questions that should not be answered, only closed down as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." What caused the typo should be disclosed in a comment only.

Comment: @RobertoBisello I don't agree though. `==` was not the only issue nor the main issue in his post. `.lower()` is really confusing for beginners, so I think this question has his place. But, I admit the title is maybe not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution, but since your learning I will try to keep it as close as your solution. Your problem is that calling `ChosenSubject.lower()` does not change the actual value in `ChosenSubject`.

Here is a working example:

```
print("Available subjects:\n-Algebra\n-Computing\n")
ChosenSubject = input("What subject would you like to do? ")

subjects = ["algebra", "computing"]
for i in range(2): 
    if ChosenSubject.lower() in subjects:
        print("\n")
        break

    else:
        print("\nPlease try again.")
        ChosenSubject = input("What subject would you like to do?") #not '=='


if ChosenSubject.lower() in subjects:
        print("working")

else:
    print("You keep typing in something incorrect.\nPlease restart the program.")
```

This from the [doc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm):

> This method returns a copy of the string in which all case-based
>   characters have been lowercased.